# jquery ajax get example

Tags: jquery, ajax, post, get

At the moment I'm using the post method like this

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Servicename.asmx/DoSomeCalculation", 
  data: "{param1ID:"+ param1Val+"}",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(msg) {
        UseReturnedData(msg.d);
    },
    error: function(err) {
        alert(err.toString());
        if (err.status == 200) {
            ParseResult(err);
        }
        else { alert('Error:' + err.responseText + '  Status: ' + err.status); }
    }
});
```

Am I correct in believing that if I use a GET request instead of POST the behavior will change to being a synchronous request i.e. the execution will wait until the response has been received from the server??

Can somebody show me a jquery GET example calling a webmethod of a web service directly?

UPDATE: Using the async flag as suggested below is really all i needed to do so this works for me. I'm still curious as to what work needs to be done to the code above to make it a GET request. Changing type: "GET" doesn't have the desired effect!

Comment: what do you mean it doesn't have the 'desired' effect? How do you know it's still POST?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can decide if you want the ajax call to be async or not using this:

```
$.ajax({
  async: false/true,
  //more options
});
```

Answer (score 6):

To answer your first point, no: GET and POST are independent of synchronous / asynchronous.

You can use the boolean `async` method to control this.

Answer (score 1):

There is a "async" flag for making the ajax call synchronous or asynchronous. You can define it as:

`$.ajax({
  async: false/true,
  //rest of code
});`

Answer (score 0):

look this sample maybe help you

```
 xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
  {
  document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
  }
  }
  xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.txt",true);
  xmlhttp.send();
```