# How to display data from AJAX call to div using Jquery or Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

In a html page when data comes through an ajax call its in this format.

```
<input type="hidden" id="s1" name="1" value="111" />
<input type="hidden" id="s2" name="2" value="222" />
```

and its loads in `<div="ajax"> Ajax data </div>`

but i have to show data in another `div` like this using jquery or javascript:

```
<div id="j1"> 111 </div>
<div id="j2"> 222 </div>
```

So i need a jquery or javascript code to handle the situation.

Comment: What code did you try to achieve that? in what way did that attempt fail?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jquery ajax get example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1459211/jquery-ajax-get-example)

Comment: Actually i need data in another div... there is no use of data in ajax div. So i need to copy data from ajax div to another div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Callback write this:

```
$('#j1').html($('#s1').val());
$('#j2').html($('#s2').val());
```

Comment: can you show response from your server side function? Just put those values in the new div using .html() method of jQuery